# gcc -Wl options : cannot pass comma inside

Tags: windows, gcc, linker, exe

I want to increase my stack and heap commit size in a PE i386 file.
if i do:

```
gcc -Wl,--stack,100000000,10000 -o stack.exe stack.c
```

it does not work.

Comment: Which version of GCC are you using?

Comment: $ gcc --version
gcc.exe (GCC) 4.8.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the -Xlinker option which is equivalent to the -Wl option:

```
gcc -Xlinker --stack=100000000,10000 -o stack.exe stack.c
```

the `-Xlinker` option can support comma.